# Using built-In SQL functions in NHIbernate Formula

Tags: nhibernate, formula

I am trying to map a NHibernate formula for a nullable datetime field that would use GetDate() if the column value is null.

The mapping I use is:

```
Map(x => x.VirtualStartDate).Formula("ISNULL(StartDate, GETDATE ())");
```

in Fluent NHibernate, which translates to hbm like this:

```
<property name="VirtualStartDate" formula="ISNULL(StartDate, GETDATE ())" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

When I try to query the database NHibernate tries to map the built-in GetDate() function to a column in the table:

```
ISNULL(workitem0_.StartDate, workitem0_.GETDATE()) as formula0_
```

Which of course doesn't work and returns an SQL error.
Is there any way to instruct NHIbernate that this is a built-in SQL function and he should leave it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved it myself, apparently it works if the sql function is written is a lower case form.